# How to move a column and its value into pivoted column in same table in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a table with some data in the following form

```
| LogDate  | AppName          | LogType | LogCount | GeneralError |
| 1-1-2017 | Registration App | Error   | 10       | 1            |
| 2-1-2017 | Reporting App    | Error   | 5        | 2            |
```

How can I move GeneralError column into LogType and achieve the following output with t-sql please?

```
| LogDate  | AppName          | LogType       | LogCount |
| 1-1-2017 | Registration App | Error         | 10       |
| 2-1-2017 | Reporting App    | Error         | 5        |
| 1-1-2017 | Registration App | GeneralError  | 1        | 
| 2-1-2017 | Reporting App    | GeneralError  | 2        |
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the unpivot like this:

```
select t.LogDate, t.AppName, v.LogType, v.LogCount
from t cross apply
     (values ('Error', t.LogCount), ('GeneralError', t.GeneralError)
     ) v(LogType, LogCount);
```

Comment: This seems like a nice query but i have 15GB of data in that database. Would this query cause an issue?

Comment: @user1534115 . . . Not more than any other query on the table that doesn't filter the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the way you stated your question you could also solve this via a union rather than a pivot construction.

```
declare @t table (logdate date, appname varchar(50), logtype varchar(50), logcount int, generalerror int)
insert into @t values ('20170101','Registration App', 'Error', 10, 1),('20170102', 'Reporting App', 'Error', 5, 2)

select  * from (
select  logdate, appname, 'Error' as logtype, Logcount 
from    @t 
union 
select  logdate, appname, 'GeneralError' as logtype, GeneralError as Logcount 
from    @t 
) x order by logdate asc
```